# Mysqldump: Restore a single backuped table to the original DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to backup a specific table using mysqldump.
I do so with this batch commandline:

```
mysqldump.exe --host=<IP> --user=<USER> --password=<PASSWORD> --port=<PORT> <DB_NAME> <TABLE_NAME> > backup.sql
```

What I receive in the resulted file are such commands:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `<TABLE_NAME>`;
CREATE TABLE `<TABLE_NAME>` (...)
```

The problem is, in this scenario the table will be created in the default DB and not necessarily in the one I intended. I would like to have something like this:

```
USE <DB_NAME>;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `<TABLE_NAME>`;
CREATE TABLE `<TABLE_NAME>` (...)
```

How could I create that using Mysqldump?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need this. When you restore the dump you use mysql (not mysqldump) and therefor you give the database as argument like you did when using the dump.

mysql -uuser -ppassword -hhost databsename < yourdumpfilename

Comment: So later on when you want to restore the dump you must remember the name of the DB it was taken from. Isn't there a way to avoid that and just run:
mysql -uuser -ppassword -hhost < yourdumpfilename
And still have inside the dump file a command to refer to the said DB?

Comment: I think this is a very dangerous way to go. It’s too easy to overwrite something you didn’t want. My dumpfilename always refers to the database it is used for. So there is no problem to identify it